# How to update entire dictionary using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I believe its quite simple but I am not able to figureout how to replace entire object using useState and setState. Here I have the empty data:

```
const emptyData = {
        "foos": {},
        "bars": {}
    };

const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(emptyData);
```

I successfully get JSON response (**response_json**) from my API call which looks like below:

```
{
    "foos": {
        "foo1": {
            "id": "foo1",
            "foo_position": {
                "pos_x": 300,
                "pos_y": 100
            },
         },
        "foo2": {
            "id": "foo2",
            "foo_position": {
                "pos_x": 300,
                "pos_y": 300
            },
         },
        "foo3": {
            "id": "foo3",
            "foo_position": {
                "pos_x": 300,
                "pos_y": 500
            },
        }
    },
    "bars": {
        "bar1": {
            "id": "bar1"
        },
        "bar2": {
            "id": "bar2"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to replace entire chart data or foos and bars which doesnt seem not to happen:

```
useEffect(() => {
        async function handlePageLoad() {
            const apiURL = getDataUrl(id);
            const response = await getData(apiURL);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const response_json = await response.json();
                setChartData(response_json);
                alert(JSON.stringify(chartData));
            }
        }
        handlePageLoad();
    }, []);
```

I also tried but no success:

```
setChartData({ ...chartData, foos: response_json.foos});
```

Edit: I put an alert to see if the data has been changed or not but I see following in the alert message which is similar to the initial data:

```
{"foos":{},"bars":{}}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: what is that inside `response_json`?

Comment: `useState` hook state updates aren't merged in, so if you simply want to fully replace existing state then `setChartData(response_json)` should do the trick provided it has the object shape you want. Perhaps I've misunderstood your question though. How are you validating that the state update ***isn't*** occurring?

Comment: `setChartData({ ...chartData, ...response_json });`

Comment: @jinongun, the Json example I've shown in the question

Comment: How do you know it's not updated? What's inside `chartData` after you set it?

Comment: @tdranv, I can see that the chartData object is not mutated. It still has the initial data i.e. { "foos": {}, "bars": {} }

Comment: Pretty obvious but... are you sure the response status is 200?

Comment: @DrewReese, I tried that as well but no luck. State update isn't happening because I always see the initial data in chartData

Comment: @tdranv, response status doesn't matter because I am can debug my code and I do see that I am trying to set valid data

Comment: ***Where*** are you seeing the initial data after you update state? Where are you looking or logging it, or whatever? You haven't provided any debugging details, and "it isn't working" isn't really how it's done. For example, even a `useEffect(() => console.log(chartData), [chartData]);` will likely show state is updating or not. React-dev-tools allow you to examine state & props in real time.

Comment: @DrewReeseis right. Perhaps a more complete example and explanation would help us help you :)

Comment: @DrewReese, tdranv, please see the updated question

Comment: React state updates are asynchronous, so if you're trying to console log or alert it right after calling `setChartData` it will always log the current state that hasn't been updated yet. Use the component lifecycle and check it in the ***next*** render cycle, that is when you can access the updated state.

Comment: The edit to the question does not add much information. Can you provide a full example of the component or reproduce it in a sandbox?

Comment: @DrewReese. I see the problem now. I didn't add a variable in useeffect. Added a refresh key did the trick. if you post your comment as answer, I can mark my question as answered. Thank you Drew and tdranv.

Comment: i think @Drew Reese is right, the result of logging the state immediately after updating it will report the stale data, because it hasn't actually been merged yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wait for the mutation to be merged. try the following to log the state after it has been updated

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function handlePageLoad() {
        const apiURL = getDataUrl(id);
        const response = await getData(apiURL);
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const response_json = await response.json();
            setChartData(response_json);
            // alert(JSON.stringify(chartData));
        }
    }
    handlePageLoad().then(() => alert(JSON.stringify(chartData)));
}, [])
```